# move_uploaded_file function not moving file

Tags: php, sql, image-upload

I'm trying to set up some image handling for a webpage I'm creating, but I can't get move_uploaded_file() to work properly.My file isn't moving to destination folder.It show the correct everything when I print variable but not moving files.
here is code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include('connection.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];

$filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$tempname = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$folder = "assets/".$filename;
if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder)){
    echo "File Moved";
}else{
    echo "File not moved";
}


// Insert Data into Database Start

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($age) && !empty($dob)  && !empty($filename)){

        $query = "INSERT INTO student_record VALUES (NULL,'$name' ,'$age','$dob' , '$folder')";
        $data = mysqli_query($conn , $query);


        if($data){
            echo "<br> Data Inserted in database";
            //header("Location: index.php");
        }
        else{
            echo "<br> Data Not Inserted! <br> $conn->error;" ;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<br>All Fields are Required! <br>";
    }
}
    else{
        echo "<br>Submit Clicked <br>";
    }

// Insert Data into Database End


?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Do you have permissions to write to the final location?

Comment: This is what I'm getting after print_r($_FILES['image']);
Array ( [name] => image.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpY0NYZf [error] => 0 [size] => 1407936 )

Comment: How to check permissions to write to the final location?

Comment: On the server you can `ls -la` the directory and see the permissions.

Comment: I'm using xampp.

Comment: Then check the Windows permissions for that directory. Also, check the error logs in `xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

Comment: I'm using MacBook. :(

Comment: Then search google for the location of the error logs on MacBook!